# Storing all even digits of an integer P in a string in the same order they appear in the integer P

Tags: c

I have a task to make a function that will take an integer as it's atribute, and store every even number in tring S, but in the order those digits appear in the integer P.
Example:

`Input: 2346`

Now I run the function and what I need as output is a string S as:

`Output: 246`

Also for

`Input: 20000`

or as many zeroes as possible, output shouldn't include zeroes, since I don't count zeroes as even numbers, so

`Output: 2`

What I've done is made a function that would just put the numbers n the reverse order, since I'm getting all digits from the right to the left.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void even(int p, char *s){
    char s1[20];
    int i,j;
    i = 0;
    while(p>0){
      if((p-(p/10)*10) %2 == 0){
        s[i] = '0' + (p-(p/10)*10);
        i++;
      };
      p = p/10;
    };

    s[i]='\0';

//The part above cuts off digits from right to left and stores them in the string S

    j=0;

    while (i>=0){
        s1[j] = s[i];
        i--;
        j++;
    };
//Part above should store the characters from the string S to the string S1 in reverse order

    i=0;
    while(s1[i]!='\0'){
        s[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    };

    s[i] = '\0';
//Code above should take the string S and replace it with the string S1 
}

int main(){

    int p;
    char s[20];

    printf("Enter P: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);

    parni(p,s);

    printf("\n\nSTRING: %s",s);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried something else out, and it worked. I first counted how many even digits there are in the integer P, and then stored those digits in the string S backward.

Here's my new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void even(int p, char *s){
    char s1[20];
    int i,j;
    i = 0;
    int k;
    k = p;

        while(p>0){
      if((p-(p/10)*10) %2 == 0){
        i++;
      };
      p = p/10;
    };

    j=i;
    i = i-1;
    p = k;
    while(p>0){
      if((p-(p/10)*10) %2 == 0){
        s[i] = '0' + (p-(p/10)*10);
        i--;
      };
      p = p/10;
    };
s[j]='\0';

}

int main(){

    int p;
    char s[20];

    printf("Enter P: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);

    even(p,s);

    printf("\n\nSTRING: %s",s);

}
```

If the input is:

`Input: 347892`

The output is:

`Output: 482`

And I'd have to correct myself, my code would actually count 0 as an even number, but I wasn't tasked with dealing with zeroes as either even or odd numbers, but making a zero as an exception would be easy.

so

`Input: 20002`

would give the same output

`Output: 20002`

Comment: Best possible scenario. You figured it out before anyone could answer! Keep up the good work.

Comment: In order to improve this answer by making it more convincing, please show your test input and the corresponding results.

Comment: I corrected myself. And about Zero being an even number. Sorry it was my mistake for not trying it out first, My test just didn't say anything about 0 being even or odd. 

Thank You @E.N.D :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you really did that the hard way.

Here's the easy way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input = 2346;
    int base = 1;
    
    while(input / base / 10) base*=10;
    
    for(; input; input%=base, base/=10)
    {
        if ((input/base) && !(input / base % 2))
        {
            printf("%d", input/base);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/GQW5yT)

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4164KB
246
```

For Input `2002`, output is `22` (ignoring the zeros, as described)

Answer (score 0):

For starters objects of the type `int` can be negative or equal to 0. Your function does not process such objects.

This loop

```
s[i]='\0';

//The part above cuts off digits from right to left and stores them in the string S    

j=0;

while (i>=0){
    s1[j] = s[i];
    i--;
    j++;
};
```

stores the terminating zero character in the beginning of the character array s1. So the next loop

```
i=0;
while(s1[i]!='\0'){
    s[i] = s1[i];
    i++;
};
```

will not be executed.

Instead of building the string manually you could use the standard C function `sprintf`.

Also it is better to declare the type of the integer as `long long int`. In this case the function will be able to process any standard integer type.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char * extract_evens( char *s, long long int x )
{
    const long long int Base = 10;
    long long int multiplier = 0;

    long long int y = 0;

    do
    {
        long long int digit = x % Base;

        if ( digit % 2 == 0 )
        {
            multiplier = multiplier == 0 ? 1 : multiplier * Base;
            y = y + multiplier * digit;
        }
    } while ( x /= Base );

    sprintf( s, "%lld", y );

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[20];

    extract_evens( s, 10001 );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", 10001ll, s );

    extract_evens( s, -10001 );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", -10001ll, s );

    extract_evens( s, LLONG_MAX );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", LLONG_MAX, s );

    extract_evens( s, LLONG_MIN );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", LLONG_MIN, s );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10001 -> 0
-10001 -> 0
9223372036854775807 -> 222068480
-9223372036854775808 -> -2220684808
```

If you do not want include zeroes then substitute this if statemen

```
if ( digit % 2 == 0 )
```

for this

```
if ( digit % 2 == 0 && digit != 0 )
```

If you may not use the function `sprintf` then the function implementation can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. In this implementation zeroes are excluded from even digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char * extract_evens( char *s, long long int x )
{
    const long long int Base = 10;
    long long int multiplier = 0;

    long long int y = 0;

    do
    {
        long long int digit = x % Base;

        if ( digit % 2 == 0 && digit != 0 )
        {
            multiplier = multiplier == 0 ? 1 : multiplier * Base;
            y = y + multiplier * digit;
        }
    } while ( x /= Base );

    char *p = s;

    if( y < 0 ) *p++ = '-';
    else if ( y == 0 ) *p++ = '0';

    for ( ; multiplier != 0; multiplier /= Base )
    {
        long long int digit = y / multiplier;
        y %= multiplier;

        if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;

        *p++ = digit + '0';
    }

    *p = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[20];

    extract_evens( s, 10001 );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", 10001ll, s );

    extract_evens( s, -10001 );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", -10001ll, s );

    extract_evens( s, LLONG_MAX );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", LLONG_MAX, s );

    extract_evens( s, LLONG_MIN );

    printf( "%lld -> %s\n", LLONG_MIN, s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10001 -> 0
-10001 -> 0
9223372036854775807 -> 2226848
-9223372036854775808 -> -22268488
```

If you want to exclude all zeroes even when the user enters 0 then just remove this statement

```
    else if ( y == 0 ) *p++ = '0';
```

in the previous demonstrative program.

In this case its output will look like

```
10001 -> 
-10001 -> 
9223372036854775807 -> 2226848
-9223372036854775808 -> -22268488
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier, faster, and simpler if one just employs a buffered [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)) directly on the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* fgets fputc ferror perror */
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT */
#include <string.h> /* strlen strchr */

int main(void) {
    char buffer[256], *b, *b_end;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
        for(b = buffer, b_end = b + strlen(b); b < b_end; b++)
            if(strchr("2468\n", *b)) fputc(*b, stdout);
    return ferror(stdin) ? (perror("stdin"), EXIT_FAILURE) : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This will also handle mis-formed input and multiple lines with no extra work, (and has error checking.) However, it assumes you have direct access to the stream as a character device; this doesn't work if you have an integer input by some other function.